# What does the html-webpack-plugin mean when it says "hash in the filename"?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I feel like the word hash gets used in so many different places and can mean different things....

1. What is an html template with a hash in the file name?

> This is a webpack plugin that simplifies creation of HTML files to
>   serve your webpack bundles. This is especially useful for webpack
>   bundles that include a hash in the filename which changes every
>   compilation. You can either let the plugin generate an HTML file for
>   you, supply your own template using lodash templates or use your own
>   loader.

source: https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin

*As a minor follow-up question*, **is there a universal definition of a "hash"?**

I've seen it used talking about cookies, URLs, authentication, in redis and data structures (e.g. hash tables)... is there any method to this madness or is it just a popular word that people decide to use when naming anything they do? I've tried to do some research on this myself but its widespread use in so many situations has made it hard to google exactly what I'm wondering about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this instance, 'hash in the filename' means that the contents of the file are hashed, which generates a sorta-unique string of characters like a1b2c3 or whatever, and is then inserted into the output filename, like `index.a1b2c3.js`. It's useful in web development because that hash will change if and only if the contents of the file change, meaning you can cache the file forever - if it changes, it'll be at a different filename.

'hash' just means to take any data of arbitrary length (contents of a file, string value, or whatever else) and construct a fixed-length, non-reversible, and almost-unique-but-not-really string value representation thereof. Without getting to far into a compsci lesson, it is very useful in various aspects of programming and is used consistently across all the instances you mentioned, as far as I know.